# Why is the class variable's value being changed when I'm changing the value in an object (Python 3.11)?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

[image: code and output]

The output should be 9 and 8 but I'm getting 9 and 9 which means the variable in the class is getting changed which shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are referring to the same class with multiple handles; you have not created any new instances of the class.

Try adding `print(rohan is harry)` to your code, and then see how the outputs change if you add the `()` to the line `rohan = Employee()`.

Comment: Thanks. I've just started leaning oops so could you elaborate on that. Are'nt harry and rohan instances of the class?

Comment: thanks.. adding ( ) after employee gave the corrrect output. Thanks a lot